# Apply bitwise operation two different folders in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitwise-and

I'm trying to combine all images one by one from two different folders, for example, I have those two folders

-folder1

-+img1.jpg

-+img2.jpg

-+img3.jpg

...

-folder2

-+img_1.jpg

-+img_2.jpg

-+img_3.jpg

what I would like to do is apply bitwise operation to img1.jpg and img_1.jpg, img2.jpg and img_2.jpg ...
I'm trying with this code in google colab but no any output

Code is as follows:

```
import os
import cv2
import pathlib
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

folder1=pathlib.Path("/content/drive/MyDrive/Healthy")
folder2=pathlib.Path("/content/drive/MyDrive/mask_Healthy")

for filename in os.listdir(folder1):
  for filename2 in os.listdir(folder2):
    if (filename == filename2):
      img1 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder1,filename),cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
      img1 = cv2.resize(img1,(224, 224))
      img2 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder2,filename2),cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
      img2 = cv2.resize(img2,(224, 224))
      dest_and = cv2.bitwise_and(img2,img1,mask = None)
      cv2_imshow(dest_and)
      make_dir(os.path.join("segmented", "seg", cv2.imwrite('filename.jpg',dest_and )))
```

Comment: Try using an absolute path when creating the result folder and make sure you have write access in that location.

Comment: `cv2.imwrite` should be called after os.path.join and make_dir. It returns True/False, not a filename as your syntax seems to expect.